# Android - Setting a bitmap as the wallpaper

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

As part of this application I am making, I want to change my wallpaper on my android device based on a bitmap that the user has selected.

I am able to change the background. However, the background is a completely distorted version of the bitmap. Any idea as to why this would happen?Here is my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)currentDrawable).getBitmap();
this.setWallpaper(bitmap);
```

My bitmap has a width of 240px and height of 180px. My emulator is of a size 480px by 800px.

I can scale my bitmap to 480px. However, the bitmap still ends up being distorted on the android wallpaper. Any thoughts on how this can be fixed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create multiple images, for each potential (and common) resolution.  You don't want any scaling, or the image will be distorted.

UPDATE:
Here is a ton of good information on support multiple screen sizes:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Hey Dave, are you saying that if I end up making the bitmap of the exact same size of the android screen resolution, then there won't be any distortion?

Comment: @roro:  That's correct.  It means that you'll need to include multiple resolutions, or you could create one image at the largest resolution you expect to encounter.  Scaling down will probably not cause as much distortion, but it may cause some.  Also look into "dx" instead of "px"- "dx" is "device-independent" pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The wallpaper used by the default Launcher is bigger than the actual screen, that's why you can scroll the content and the wallpaper too.